# wdfs mount problem

Tags: fedora, filesystems, files, ls, webdav

I'm running Fedora/Gnome 3.4.2 64bit and I'm trying to mount a webdav file system to work with.

As root, I run the command

```
#mkdir /mnt/webdav
#wdfs https://www.webiste.com:port/directory /mnt/webdav -o allow_other
```

It asks for the user and pass which I provide and then gives me back the prompt. Then I go and check /mnt/webdav and there are no files. Either as root or my normal user.

Then, to try and see what is happening I try

```
#cd /mnt
#ls
ls: cannot access webdav: No such file or directory
webdav
#
```

So webdav doesn't exist but bash lists it as a folder? 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webdav` entry appears in the directory listing for `/mnt`, but when `ls` tries to read the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) of `/mnt/webdav`, it is told that no such file exist. Contrast:

```
# \ls /mnt
webdav
# ls
ls: cannot access webdav: No such file or directory
webdav
```

That's whatever alias you're using for `ls` (typically `ls -F` or `ls --color`) causing `ls` to read the metadata on `/mnt/data` (calling [`stat(2)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29)) and failing.

Wdfs is having trouble connecting to the server. To see what the error is, check the system logs or try to run wdfs in a more verbose mode, or snoop on your network traffic.